# Plot: how to change the breaks?

Tags: r, range, break, survival

I'm plotting a survival curve with the `survival` library, and I haven't found any way to change the breaks range.

For example:

```
library(survival)
temps <- c(5,15,25,30,18,16,38,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40)
deces <- c(1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
plot(survfit(Surv(temps,deces)~1))
```

Gives us this plot:

[image]

If I want, I can change the range of the whole axis with `xlim=c()`, the scale of abscissa numbers with `xscale`.

But the x breaks ranges will always stay at every 5 or 10 units (10,20,30,40).
It's impossible to change them to 12 for example, as I want (12, 24,36,...) because they should represent months.

Is this possible to change them? Or do I have to use the `survminer` library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To customized the axes, save the `survfit` object and plot it with graphics parameter `xaxt = "n"`, meaning, **no `x` axis**. Then plot the `x` axis with `axis()`.

```
library(survival)

temps <- c(5,15,25,30,18,16,38,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40)
deces <- c(1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

sv <- survfit(Surv(temps, deces) ~ 1)
plot(sv, xaxt = "n")
axis(1, at = seq(0, max(temps) + 12, by = 12))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I was never used to doing this way, now I learned!